# How to use methods function in vue js to give thousand separator in my props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

im newbie on vue js, i wanna try to give thousand separator on my props price using my methods function called 'thousandSeparator' but i got stuck how to use that.

i have done to parsing props price but the price not separated with thousand yet. i have props price which is >= 1000. but i wanna render it with separator dot (ex: 1.000, 10.000).
this is my code

```
<template>
  <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 18rem">
    <img :src="image" class="card-img-top image" alt="..." />
    <div class="card-body text-start">
      <h5 class="card-title title">{{name}}</h5>
      <h6 class="price">Rp. {{price}}</h6>
      <p class="card-text description">
        {{description}}
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary d-block button-add-cart">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Card',
    props: ['name', 'price', 'description', 'image'],
    methods: {
      thousandSeparator(price: number) {
        return price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
      }
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using computed like:

```
computed: {
   priceWithThousandSeparator(){
      return this.price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
}
```

After that use this:
`<h6 class="price">Rp. {{ priceWithThousandSeparator }}</h6>`